# Something has happend to Nicematrix. The code doesn't work

Tags: nicematrix

I might be wrong but the package nicematrix doesn't seem to behave like it used to. The output of the code below doesn't have any colored rows and gives several error messages.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,nicematrix}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test  1}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{clr}[hvlines]
    \CodeBefore
    \rowcolors[gray]{2}{0.8}{}[cols=2-3,restart]
    \Body
    \Block{1-*}{Results} \\
    John & 12 \\
    Stephen & 8 \\
    Sarah & 18 \\
    Ashley & 20 \\
    Henry & 14 \\
    Madison & 15
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test  2}

    $\begin{pNiceMatrix}[columns-width = 20pt,margin=5pt,cell-space-limits = 10pt]
        \phantom{} & I & II & III & IV \\
        A & 15 & 3 & 30 & 20 \\
        B & 20 & 2 & 20 & 30\\
        C & 40 & 20 & 10 & 40 \\
        D & 5 & 30 & 40 & 40
        \CodeAfter\SubMatrix({2-2}{5-5})
    \end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which version of the `nicematrix` package did you use to compile your code and which error messages do you get specifically?

Comment: Use `\begin{NiceTabular}{cl}[hvlines]`. The tabular only has 2 columns.

Comment: I don't know the version since I use overleaf. I assume that it is the latest.

Comment: Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: There is three columns since because of the command ```\Block{1-*}{Results}``` which should produce a merged first column.

Comment: Thanks @F.Pantigny that did the trick! Now it works just fine.