# How to create a matrix with leading diagonal submatrices being framed in Latex using nicematrix package?

Tags: nicematrix

I want to create a matrix with leading diagonal submatrices being framed, showed in below graph
[image]

I tried using **nicematrix** package, and my latex code with *beamer* on overleaf is as follows:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, 11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}       
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\[ 
M = \begin{bNiceArray}{*{5}{c}}[margin=0.5em]
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} & \Sigma_{13} & \Sigma_{14} & \Sigma_{15} \\[5pt]
\Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22} & \Sigma_{23} & \Sigma_{24} & \Sigma_{25} \\[5pt]
\Sigma_{31} & \Sigma_{32} & \Sigma_{33} & \Sigma_{34} & \Sigma_{35} \\[5pt]
\Sigma_{41} & \Sigma_{42} & \Sigma_{43} & \Sigma_{44} & \Sigma_{45} \\[5pt]
\Sigma_{51} & \Sigma_{52} & \Sigma_{53} & \Sigma_{54} & \Sigma_{55} \\
\CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) [draw=red, thick, fit=(1-1) (2-2)] {} ;
    \node (B) [draw=red, thick, fit=(2-2) (3-3)] {} ; 
    \node (C) [draw=red, thick, fit=(3-3) (4-4)] {} ;
    \node (D) [draw=red, thick, fit=(4-4) (5-5)] {} ; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bNiceArray}
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But after a super-long time compile, it gave me error saying "
[image]
[image]

"

I've already followed the instructions in *[Something has happend to Nicematrix. The code doesn't work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615784/something-has-happend-to-nicematrix-the-code-doesnt-work)* and downloaded the **nicematrix.txt** file and uploaded in the overleaf folder where my project locates and renamed the file into **nicematrix.sty**.

Comment: Welcome. Not on Overleaf, but I get the result in a very short time and it's correct.

Comment: With `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` added in your code, I have no error to compile it with Overleaf (TeXLive 2021 and TeXLive 2020).

Comment: @F. Pantigny. But I tried again, and still need a long time to compile and gave the same error message. I'm thinking maybe I did not tackle the nicematrix.sty properly. I went to the website and downloaded the nicematrix.txt file, then saved it as nicematrix.sty, and then uploaded into the folder where my main.tex lies on overleaf. Could you confirm whether this process is right or not? Thank you!

Comment: @F. Pantigny Also, I'm not sure where to add the \begin{document} and \end{document} since i'm doing slides, so I first \begin{frame} \end{frame}, then inside I did \begin{document} and \end{document} . But it also gave error message saying timed out. I then tried to reverse the order with begin{document} and \end{document} first, then within this pair include \begin{frame} \end{frame}, but still timed out.

Comment: I have added `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in your code. In Overleaf (without any other file: there is need to have the latest version of `nicematrix` to compile this code), I have compiled without any problem.

Comment: @F. Pantigny. Hi, I went to https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty and downloaded Revision 63912 version of nicematrix and save the file as .sty. I notice my code has `\begin{document} ` and `\end{document}` already. Where do you suggest I add one more pair? Thanks!

Comment: @F. Pantigny. Again, I got the same timed out warning and failed to compile again.

Comment: @Alison: Send me a email (fpantigny@wanadoo.fr) and I will send you a link to a Overleaf project.

Comment: @F. Pantigny: thank you very much!